# Embed Silverlight Video Player to Asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I embed my custom Silverlight Video Player application into an Asp.net web application?

I Tried to get more info. about this, 
it is the first time to deal with silverlight on Asp.net so
i get searched for it in [silverlight.com](http://www.silverlight.net/archives/videos/add-a-silverlight-application-to-an-aspnet-page)

i'm already new to [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
so, i donno well in its rules

anyway thanks Guys, this answers really help. :)

Comment: With code. (Note: I've used the same level of detail in my answer as you used in your question)

Comment: -1 Your question does not indicate any research effort.

Comment: normally you want to provide as much detail as possible in your questions. i.e. what you have tried, what code you have so far, etc.

Comment: You can Google the answer you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very broad and ambiguous, but I will attempt to provide an answer to what I think you're looking for:

Assuming you already have an .xap file (that is, the file produced by building a Silverlight Application in Visual Studio 2010), you can simply embed it in any HTML or ASPX page by using the code that Visual Studio automatically generates for you when you create a new Silverlight Application with a Web project:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>SilverlightApplication1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost {
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            var appSource = "";
            if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
              appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
            }

            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
              return;
            }

            var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

            errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
            errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
            errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

            if (errorType == "ParserError") {
                errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
                if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                    errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                    errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
                }
                errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
            }

            throw new Error(errMsg);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I had this code automatically generated in VS2010 by going to File->New Project->Silverlight Application and checking the box for "Host the Silverlight Application in a new Web site" and opening up the SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx file that was created in my SilverLightApllication1.Web project.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ASP.NET project in the same solution as your Silverlight project, and then add an object tag in your .aspx page that references the XAP file which is the output of the Silverlight project.

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightVideoPlayer.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```